# Nifi:Does Invokehttp works Asynchronously?

Tags: apache-nifi

I  have service  which  should  get  person data  based on their id. if  i  have person  idies  like :1,2,3,4,5  and perhaps  person  id  with 3  fails

1. How can i find which response  has  failed does it sends 1 request 
   with id 1 and  then wait  until response will be send  or it sends and reitreives data asynchronously?

Answer (score 2):

InvokeHttp routes flowfiles to different output relationships based on the status of the response (see [Relationships in InvokeHttp](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html#relationships)).

To handle the individual responses for your person IDs, you will want to make sure that each is split out into its own flowfile.  You will also want to have distinct output queues for each relationship, so you can retry, log, or otherwise handle each response.